# Definition of Clifford Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, clifford-algebras

Cliffard algebra defined by relation:
$x*y+y*x=g(x,y)1$, where g(x,y) is bilinear symmetric form.
What does mean $g(x,y)1$, why it's not just $g(x,y)$, without the identity?

Comment: $1$ denotes the identity element for $\ast$, it is an element of the algebra, while 'pure scalars' might not be.

Comment: @Berci thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bilinear form $g$ is real-valued. But $x*y+y*x$ should be an element of the Clifford algebra. Hence you multiply $g(x,y)$ by $1$, which sits in the Clifford algebra, so that $g(x,y)\cdot 1$ is an element of the Clifford algebra.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it. But, if V is space over a field k, Cl(V) should be over $\mathbb{R}*k$? Because I don't understand how I can multiply real number with a element from some field.

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space over a field $k$, then the Clifford algebra is an algebra over $k$. In that case $g$ is $k$-valued.

Comment: Oh yes, I got it. Thank you!